# SET-ADACCOUNTPASSWORD Exception

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I am trying to run this command, on running it ..it does prompt me for desired passwords but then it shows me this error "A referral is sent from the server"

Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity myidhere -server "servernamehere"

Running this on PowerShell on windows 2008 R2, the Domain controller is Read-Only and is in different domain

Comment: Yes. I am running it as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617261.aspx

```
Notes

•
This cmdlet does not work with an Active Directory Snapshot.
This cmdlet does not work with a read-only domain controller. This cmdlet does not work when connected to Global Catalog port.
```

Edit to add some info for RODCs:

•A read-only AD Domain Services (AD DS) database--Applications that need only database read access can use the RODC; however, any database changes must be made to a read-writable DC (RWDC), then replicated back to the RODC.

•Limited credential caching--An RODC doesn't store user or computer credentials (except for the RODC's computer account). When the RODC receives an authentication request, it forwards it to an RWDC. The RODC then requests a copy of the credential so that it can service the request itself in the future. If the password-replication policy allows credential caching, the credential details will be cached and the RODC can service logon requests `(until the credentials change).` **No credentials change can be made on a RODC!**

Comment: I have a question, that when I change the password from windows security it does changes the password but when Im doing it through scripts like powershell or .net code it tells me that "domain controller does not exist or couldnt be contacted". Let me add that I am talking to a read-only domain controller, and the same code works on the other environment when I talk to a non-read-only domain controller.

Comment: 'when I change the password from windows security' are you talking about the 'change password..' button after ctrl+alt+canc or from the ADUC mmc console?

Comment: in this case the DC used by windows is surely the one not-read-only to accomplish the change password. Change the value of `-server` parameter to a non-read-only DC to use `set-AdAccountPassword`

Comment: but my user exists in the read-only-dc and I am logged in to the machine by authenticating through the rodc. Can the windows still be using the non-rodc, is it possible ? I am not sure. Your thoughts?

Comment: Edit my answer. I think you can delete your other questions about this stuff ;)